# Traversing a nested XML structure with XSLT template

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I have looked through the different solutions in this forum but my problem is a little different. Suppose we have a xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transaction>
    <operation>DEBIT</operation>
    <autoRegistration>true</autoRegistration>
    <allowRecurrence>true</allowRecurrence>
    <network>VISA</network>
    <source>RANDOM</source>
    <origin>
        <merchant>ABC</merchant>
        <transactionId>1234</transactionId>
        <channel>SINGLE</channel>
        <country>DE</country>
    </origin>
    <customer>
        <number>338317</number>
        <eMail>someone@somewhere.de</eMail>
        <dateOfBirth>1975-06-15</dateOfBirth>
        <contact>
            <eMail>someone@somewhere.de</eMail>
            <phoneNumbers></phoneNumbers>
        </contact>
        <clientInfo>
            <ip>123.111.123.123</ip>
            <userAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)</userAgent>
            <acceptHeader>*/*</acceptHeader>
        </clientInfo>
    </customer>
</Transaction>
```

Suppose I need to transform this to CSV using XSLT. I need my CSV as follows:

```
operation,allowRecurrence,source,merchant
DEBIT,true,RANDOM,ABC
```

The real world problem is more complex with more nested xml elements. How should I design my XSLT for such a problem such that it handles multiple levels of nested XML elements and prepares a CSV for me.
So far I have managed to put together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->
    <xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
        <field>operation</field>
        <field>allowRecurrence</field>
        <field>source</field>
        <field>merchant</field>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="currNode" select="."/>
        <!-- output the header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- output newline -->
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields" >
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*/*[name() = current()]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am stuck at the logic `<xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*/*[name() = current()]"/>`... How do I vary the level of XML element nesting in this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML documents are not "arbitrary"; they follow a pre-defined schema. Your best strategy is to tailor your XSLT to the expected schema. In your example, that would mean something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Transaction">
    <xsl:text>operation,allowRecurrence,source,merchant,eMail&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="operation"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="allowRecurrence"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="source"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="origin/merchant"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="customer/eMail"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your idea of traversing the document, looking for a node named 'xyx' would fail when there are multiple nodes with the same name. For example, your XML has two `eMail` nodes, and your method would never reach the one at `customer/contact/eMail`.

Comment: Perhaps that's molbal's way to react to criticism? +1 of course.

Comment: @molbal You should address your comment to Mathias.